# String compare being weird

Tags: c++

Ive been racking my brain here:

```
cout << orig << " * " << count << endl;
string check = multiply2(orig, count);
cout << "Check was: " << check << " and number is: " << number << endl;
cout << "the compare result: " << check.compare(number) <<  endl;
if(check.compare(number) == 0)
{
  cout << "wahoo it matches!!! we did it! " << endl;
}
else
{
  cout << "Doesnt Match " << endl;
}
```

I'm expecting it to match and print `wahoo it matches!!! we did it!` but its instead saying it doesn't match.

Here is my output:

```
1 * 900000
Check was: 900000 and number is: 90000
the compare result: 1
Doesnt Match
```

Anyone have idea why they arent matching?

Comment: What are their respective types? How have you set them up?

Comment: Hmm, one number has 5 digits and the other has 6....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You compare `900000` (as in 9E5) versus `90000` (as in 9E4). Computer is right.

Comment: Computers are pretty good at this stuff. I wish I was a computer.

Comment: After coding for 24 hours on an assignment it's easy to miss the simple things ;)